# cannot convert from 'string' to 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUserRole

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2017

I'm fairly new with updating databases, and I've constructed the below code to replace a user's role with a new role. I'm getting the error in the subject though.

```
    public void UpdateRole(string id, string newRoleID)
    {
        var user = Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == id);
        var oldRoleId = user.Roles.FirstOrDefault().RoleId;
        if (user != null && oldRoleId != newRoleID)
        {
            user.Roles.Remove(oldRoleId);
            user.Roles.Add(newRoleID);
        }
    }
```

Could someone please explain why I am getting this error? I am not trying to convert anything. I am attempting to delete the contents of RoleId for the user id specified, and replace it with the new ID that is sent from my post action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`user.Roles.Add` method takes a `IdentityUserRole` object while you are passing it a `string` value (i.e. `newRoleID`). You need the following change in you code:

```
user.Roles.Add(new IdentityUserRole { RoleId = newRoleID });
```

**Edit**
The `Remove` method, needs an `IdentityUserRole` object too. But note that it must be attached to the context too. The simplest way you can do it is through the following code:

```
    var user = Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == id);
    var oldRole = user.Roles.FirstOrDefault();
    if (user != null && oldRole.RoleId != newRoleID)
    {
        user.Roles.Remove(oldRole);
        user.Roles.Add(new IdentityUserRole { RoleId = newRoleID });
    }
```

Comment: Awesome - so with that being said, then removing is the same and I should change my remove code to `user.Roles.Remove(new IdentityUserRole { RoleId = oldRoleId });`?

Comment: Yes, the `remove` method also needs an `IdentityUserRole` object, but the object to be deleted needs to be attached to the context too, check the **edit**.

Comment: Just checked. I believe I understand now. I did change `oldRole.Id` to `oldRole.RoleId` though. .Id is specific to `IdentityUser`, while .RoleId is specific to `IdentityUserRole`.